# AWS DynamoDB filterexpression having multiple IN conditions clause with QueryRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

When we using multiple IN conditions clause with QueryRequest, it only data which matches with the first item provided in IN condition.

I have Json format has

```
{
[
  {
   CID:1,
   PId:1,
  },
  {
   CID:2,
   PID:2,
  }
],
Age:30,
STATE:[
    "AP", "TS"
],
Brands:[
  "SAMSUNG","NOKIA","LG"
]
} 

var filterExpression = " ((#CID= :CID1 and #PID = :PID1) or (#CID = :CID2 and #PID = :PID2)  and #State in ( :state1, :state2) and #Brands in ( :brands1, :brands2)";
                // Create Query request
                QueryRequest request1 = new QueryRequest
                {
                    TableName = "Table1",
                    IndexName = "Age-index",
                    KeyConditionExpression = "Age = :Age",
                    FilterExpression = filterExpression,
                    ExpressionAttributeNames = expressionAttributeNames,
                    ExpressionAttributeValues = expressionAttributeValues
                };

                var result = await dynamoClient.QueryAsync(request1);
```

Comment: can u please write what you want?

Comment: Code working fine, I figure that there was a data issue. Due to this, the provided combination doesn't have data to retrieve.
Thanks, IftekharDani for responding to this question.